# Help to identify font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

can someone help to identify what font is below:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a light weight of Bookman. The wide a, high pointed t and thick serifs on the F are all very similar. Maybe Mark Simonson's Bookmania.

If you want the *original* font the wobbling baseline makes it look like this was done on a VIP typewriter which could do proportional letters. (variable width) Maybe check out IBM's specimens of fonts for their composer line. These generally haven't been digitised, but the style is very similar to Bookman. All these designs ultimately trace back to a very popular font called Old Style cut in Edinburgh by Alexander Phemister for Miller & Richard.